How to create zip from multiple azure blob files?
I have a case where I need to provide a zip file to download from browser from the multiple files in the Azure blob storage?
I believe that this can't be done with out downloading the files to a machine and the pack it.
(I use Azure functions for API's, so downloading them to function memory is not kinda good & end zip file could be ~5 GB)
Are there any other alternatives to achieve this?

Data Factory can easily handle zipping Blob folders and files, is that an option for you?

Thanks @JoelCochran this looks like a solution that works for my use case.

Best to include work you've done, along with a specific issue (a [mcve]). Right now, you've only provided a set of requirements.


create zip from multiple azure blob files?

I agree with Joel Cochran's comment, you can use the Azure Data factory to zip multiple files from azure blob storage.
First create destination container to store all blob files into zip format from source container.
Portal:
These are the files stored in the source container

Now, I created the Binary dataset for both source and destination container. In the source dataset give the path till the required folder.
Portal:

In the destination, give your path and compression type ZipDeflate(.zip) like below,
Portal:

Execute the copy activity and you will see the required file in the destination container with zip file.
Output:


Now, you can download the zipped files from Azure blob storage.
Reference:
Copy and transform data in Azure Blob Storage - Azure Data Factory & Azure Synapse | Microsoft Learn

fyi the OP hasn't shown any work and only posted a set of requirements. Please don't answer off-topic questions (the question is open-ended, without any details from the OP). The suggestion of using ADF, in a comment, is fine - lets the OP explore that option, but there's no reason to build an entire solution (this is not what Stack Overflow is for)

Thank you Venkatesan, for the detailed solution. I have tried POC earlier today and was able to generate zip, also fyi found another potential solution(which includes Azure Durable fn. with Stream, haven't tried it yet thought).
